# iOS Update causes iCloud Photo Library issues

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud, photos

I just updated my iPhone 7 to iOS 11.4 and this seems to cause some issues to my Photos.app library. I'm using iCloud Photo library and right now when I checked the amount of Photos in the "Albums" view of Photos.app on iOS the amount of pictures is way lower.

Also some old pictures are suddenly showing up mixed in with the last photos I took a few hours ago.

When I check "Photos" it tells me "Uploading 7.xxx Items" at the bottom.

Does anyone have a clue what's going on there and how to fix it?

Comment: Had the same issue after updating to iOS 11.4 yesterday. I don't know if I lost photos but there were duplicates with the wrong date (so at the wrong place in Moments). The only solution I found is to look for duplicates with a software and to delete ones with the wrong date. Additionally before doing anything check your "Recently Deleted" folder as well as "All Photos" to look for potentially unwanted deletion/addition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I talked to the Apple Support and their solution was to...wait. So I waited until everything was uploaded again. This took around 12h. Then it started downloading files again, then it switched to "Updating" and then everything was fine again.

The person on the hotline said that it has to "upload" (It actually just checks if it's already on the server, not actually uploads the file) the file. Then it downloads what's missing and fills up the missing ones.